# Request focus of view and place it on top of the screen within a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

See bottom of this entry for an answer to this "problem".

In my app I inflate some xml views and add them to a LinearLayout, list,  within a ScrollView. The XML looks like this:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="19"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I then try to give focus to one of the views I've put into 'list'. This is done by using this code :

```
view.getParent().requestChildFocus(view, view);
```

If the above code results in a scroll down, the focused view get placed at the bottom of the screen and if it result in a scroll up, the focused view get placed at the top of the screen.

Is there a way to make the focused view always get placed at the top of the screen if the length of the list permits it?

Edit: This works! See accepted answer.

XML

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="19"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Sample code to put somewhere in your activity or fragment

```
view = findViewById(get_view_that_should_have_focus);
ScrollView scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scroll_list);
scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, view.getTop());
```

Comment: could you give more detail , maybe pic's of what is happening ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can vertical scroll to specific view by using this:

```
scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0,view.getTop());
```

It will make your view top of the scrollview(if there is enough height) After scrolling, you can request focus for this view.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment, I'm just gonna post this here. 
The solution provided by [Oğuzhan Döngül](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36371994/14623286) is correct, but if some of you can't get it running, try to do the `smoothScroll` inside runnable :

```
 val topOffset = view.height
 scrollView.post {
    scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, view.top - topOffset)
 }
```

I add `topOffset` to give some spaces on top of the highlighted view.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3263540/14623286)